# Converting HTML to String is crashing when running UITests

Tags: swift, string, nsattributedstring, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to convert HTML response from RSS Feed to String and display in UILabel.

Here is my code in String extension:

```
var html2AttributedString: NSAttributedString? {

    guard
        let data = data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        else { return nil }

    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data , options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print("error:", error)
        return nil
    }
}
var html2String: String {
    return html2AttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
```

Here is where I call this:

```
self.lblDescription.text = article.articleDescription.html2String
```

This code is working when I run the application and never it crashed. But when I run this code in the TestUI it is crashing sometimes (2 out of 5):

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let tablesQuery = app.tables
```

And here is the error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1827ece5c)


    0x10095a350 <+132>: ldr    x21, [sp, #0x40]
    0x10095a354 <+136>: bl     0x10095c7d4               ; @nonobjc (extension in UIKit):__ObjC.NSAttributedString.init(data: Foundation.Data, options: Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, documentAttributes: Swift.Optional<Swift.AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Optional<__ObjC.NSDictionary>>>) throws -> __ObjC.NSAttributedString at AppExtensions.swift
->  0x10095a358 <+140>: mov    x8, x21
    0x10095a35c <+144>: mov    x1, x8
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a crash message? I run into similar crashes a couple of times and they were always mentioning an AX deadlock.

Comment: This isn't a crash, you are on an exception breakpoint. Your catch block will handle the error.